# Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm writing an upload control that works with a WCF service and when I'm trying to upload files over 1MB I'm getting this Error:

```
{System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: 
 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the 
     software in your host machine
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)}
```

I don't know if this is related to json max length parameter or not.
I know that in web applications I can add this to the web.config file

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```

But I'm new to WCF and have no idea how to handle it here...

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

1. remove the `[WebInvoke...]` and leave only the `[OperationContract]` in the interface
2. Use these config files

Client config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>

        <binding name="WebHttpBinding_IAttachmentService" closeTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00" receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>

          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:54893/AttachmentService.svc"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IAttachmentService"
                behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
                contract="XXX.Interfaces.IAttachmentService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Service config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="XXX.Implementation.AttachmentService">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
                  bindingConfiguration="higherMessageSize"
                  contract="XXX.Interfaces.IAttachmentService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="higherMessageSize" transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00" receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>

          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
     <handlers>
         <remove name ="WebDAV"/>
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting a timeout. First of all, turn the keepalive  on in your binding. Second, check the timestamps on the request and reply. If there is a firewall between the sender and receiver, make sure that it isn't closing the connection because of idle timeout.

Comment: The keepAlive is true by default, and I don't think it has somethig to do with timeout here because the exception is thrown immediately.